# How to design RESTful API for hierarchical entities

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing RESTful API for file storage and having problems with finding the best way to organize URL's to actions.

Files can be grouped to folders but it is needed to be able to get all the files.
Guidelines suggests to use the following url to get files for specific folder.

`GET /folders/{folderName}/files`

But what should be used to just get all files? `GET /files` or `GET /folders/files`?

Also Google Drive has somewhat similar functionality and they use diifferent approach

`GET files/{folderName}/children`

Comment: What do you get if you browse `/folders/{folderName}`? It seems to me that `files` might be removed in all urls but I could be wrong

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about it. But then again, what should be done to get all files regardless of folders (I have such requirements)

Comment: In that case. I'd use `/folders/`. In theory, that endpoint is only supposed to return root folders, but you could use a querystring parameter to expand response to the entire tree. Not 100% rest, but don't think it's very practical to make 1000 server calls to get the full tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed this can range from one API designer to another.

If I was facing this problem I would want to consider all use cases and figure out what works best.

It looks like the following would meet your needs:

```
GET /                                    Retrieves all files and folders
GET /{folderId}                          Retrieves all contents of said folderId (folders and files)
GET /{fileId}                            Retrieves the file
GET /{folderId}/{folderId}               Same as above, but for nested folder
GET /{folderId}/{folderId}/{fileId}      Retrieves the file
```

this pattern can continue for however nested the file structure is (note there is a limit on URL length)

Then if you have a unique requirement such as all you just create a new api endpoint.

```
GET /files/                              Retrieves all files
GET /files/?filter="*.txt"               Retrieves all text files
```

So to answer your EXACT question of:

> But what should be used to just get all files? GET /files or GET
>   /folders/files

I would lean towards /files instead of /folders/files. /folders/files does not make much sense as an api consumer.